# PIXI Webgl memory leak

Tags: webgl, pixi.js

Hi I am using PIXI and I am destroying textures whenever necessary. I am seeing that in the chrome task manager, the image cache and other resources are consuming very less memory. My only problem is with the new screens and textures getting loaded, the GPU memory increases (Like 5-10 mb on every activity). I am using texture.destroy(true) to destroy resources. I am also destroying base textures. I am also logging PIXI.utils.TextureCache and PIXI.utils.BaseTextureCache and I am seeing that the number of objects in these are bare minimum required for my app.

I am also making use of PIXI Animated Sprite. If it consumes any extra resources which I should be worried about, please let me know.

I am not sure where the webgl memory is increasing. I am using webgl because I make extensive usage of filters which is not possible using canvas renderer. Can any one help on how do I debug the memory usage and delete unnecessary textures from webgl. I am running on a tight timeline, so any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide example code?

Comment: You could also verify the issue with different device and browser if possible. I think the destroy should work quite easily, unless you forget to clean some specific sprite. Not sure about animated sprites though.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot provide any code. Say I am using sprite = new AnimatedSprite(frames), and in destroy method, I am using, for all preloaded images, if(texture.basetexture) texture.baseTexture.destroy(true) and texture.destroy(true). no images being cached in chrome memory.In chrome taskmanager, I am seeing the GPU memory is constantly increasing. In GL inspector, I am seeing that the textures used previously are striked out, but are still showing up in the inspector.I have noticed the GL memory is not storing all preloaded sprites, but only ones that are displayed on the screen.